# Communicating with Google Spreadsheet loaded in an iframe

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet loaded in an iFrame. Outside the iFrame I have a button. When the user clicks the button. I need to retrieve the data in the current row. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: What is your site hosted on? Google Sites or something else ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible at all. Browsers don't allow you to mess with the iframe content if it's a different domain.

Comment: @Srik My site is hosted on one of my own servers.

Comment: @EduardoCereto - I'm not looking to retrieve the contents in the iFrame by parsing the page loaded in the iFrame. Is there some service, like a REST api or something using which I can query the spreadsheet in the context of an authorized user and get the data

Comment: I'm afraid Eduardo is correct. You can't do that. If you were on Google Sites, you could perhaps write a script that did both displaying the spreadsheet and handling the button click within it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write a script and publish it as a web app that acts as an API. You could use this to query the spreadsheet in the context of an authorized user (Google account) and get the data. The script would use the ContentService and give you back TextOutput of mimeType JSON (or Atom, RSS, XML or text). This is just new functionality but the doc is in place. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_content